# How do I brace shed walls against shear when sheathing cannot overlap rim joist?

Tags: walls, framing, shed, earthquake

I'm building an 8' by 13.5' shed with a loft. I [posted previously](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/205144/floor-frame-for-8-wide-shed-is-3-too-wide-on-either-side) about the floor frame being slightly larger than the planned floor. Below is the intended floor framing, as seen in the plan:
[image: dimensioned view of floor framing]

Here is the current execution (joists have been installed as above but are omitted from the diagram; red area is where subfloor and walls actually sit):
[image: view from above of floor superimposed on frame, excluding joists]

Consequently, the outer face of each side wall (2x4 thickness) is inset about 3" from the outer edge of the beam below it (three sistered 2x6s). Here is a cross-section of a side wall:

[image: components of wall and floor framing]

I have nailed the bottom plate to the 2x6 below, but could not overlap the sheathing past the bottom plate and nail it to the rim board (like I did on the rear wall) because of how the rim board juts out. I plan on adding flashing to avoid moisture seepage into the plywood.

The current connection between walls and floor is rather dinky and I would like to ensure that shear bracing is adequate, especially since I live in a relatively earthquake-prone location. Can I use another method, e.g. using steel strapping to attach the wall framing to the rim board at studs? If so, can I bend the strapping so that it conforms to the outer surface of the rim board and wall?

Comment: Maybe @leesam or someone with an engineering inclination can weigh in, but that's a tiny structure. My gut tells me that just nailing off the perimeter/field thoroughly will give you all the shear you need. If you didn't have windows, you could also let in some bracing, but I sincerely believe that's overkill.

Comment: I'm baffled why you didn't move the walls out to be flush with the outside of the rim joists and grab the extra 6" of interior floor space, but I guess it's too late for that.

Comment: I'm at the upper limit of interior space for an auxiliary building not requiring a permit in my area. Also, my lumber is sized for an 8' width.